# Symfony form submission with handleRequest issue

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4, symfony-validator

I'm experiencing an odd error with my form validation in Symfony 4. It is a simple contact form represented by this entity:

```
class ContactRequest
{
    /** @var int */
    private $id;
    
    /** @var string */
    private $fullName;
    
     //...
    
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullName() : string
    {
        return $this->fullName;
    }
```

In my controller I'm handling the submission as per Symfony website but there is something I'm missing for I'm getting the following error:

`Type error: Return value of App\Entity\ContactRequest::getFullName() must be of the type string, null returned`

Now, I know what is the meaning of that: it expects a string to be returned by the method `getFullName` whereas `null` is actually returned but I don't understand why.

This is my controller

```
   public function contactSubmit(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator)
   {

        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
          //...
        }

        $errors = $validator->validate($form);
```

Shouldn't the `handleRequest()` method set the values in the entity for me?

To my surprise, when I have initialised the entity before, it worked well notwithstanding the entity is already set in the `configureOptions()` method in the form:

```
$contact = new ContactRequest;
$contact
    ->setFullName($request->request->get('contact')['fullName'])
    //...

    $form = $this->createForm(
        ContactType::class
        $contact
    );
    $form->setData($contact);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

However, shouldn't the scope of using the `handleRequest()` be to avoid setting the entity's values manually? Shouldn't the `handleRequest()` method take care of setting those values?
I know I could validate the submitted data against the entity too (thing that I've successfully tried), without using the `handleRequest()` at all but it would piss me off a little. Why would I need to set a form in such a case?

This is the `ContactType` form:

```
 //...
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
        $builder
            ->add('fullName', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'empty_data' => 'a',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Full Name',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
        //...
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ContactRequest::class
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You're missing the 2nd parameter to `createForm` (a reference to a `ContactRequest` instance). How should `handleRequest` know where to set the data?

Comment: The ```ContactRequest``` reference is already set in the form ```configureOptions``` method. However, even if I pass it as you said like this ```$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, new ContactRequest); ```, the problem is still there, unless I set manually the data in the entity using the setters

Comment: Try setting it to a variable first, eg: `$contactRequest = new ContactRequest(); $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contactRequest);`. It might also help if you post the full controller - just in case... Doing `new -> createForm -> handleRequest -> isValid` should definately be enough.

Comment: I've already tried everything of that. Nothing changes

Comment: I guess the logic solution is to just remove the type hint then (since you basically are initializing the entity with a null value in that field). PHP only supports nullable type hints with v7.1 (`?string` would be the syntax there)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. That is what I've done at the moment although it looks a bit dirty to me for it's not supposed to return null whatsoever. Cheers :)

Comment: The problem seems to be the following: In a normal lifecycle that controller is executed twice. 1st on the GET request of the page, in this one no submission is actually taking place (and thus handleRequest will do nothing and fullName will stay `NULL`).. I guess this is the request that throws the error. The 2nd request would be the POST when the form is actually sent to the controller with data, this one **might** run properly, depending on the order of your other calls inside the controller. We could analyze this further, but we'd need the whole stacktrace instead of just the last line.

Comment: @ccKep is right. Just to add you can make getFullName(): ?string to avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So far the only solution I came up with is to consider null params as suggested by @ccKep (```getFullName(): ?string```).
Weird though it may look, the request is executed only once on POST action (this is actually only a POST method), therefore the handle request is executed only once on POST. I made sure to not call it under any other circumstance

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out where your `getFullName` gets called you could (atleast in dev environment) print the backtrace on the call:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullName() : string
{
    if ($this->fullName === null)
    {
        echo "<pre>getFullName on uninitialized entity:\n";
        debug_print_backtrace();
        die();
    }
    return $this->fullName;
}
```

But as said in the comments: Initializing the entity with a null value in that field and not allowing the getter to return a null value seems kinda odd to me, so `: ?string` to allow for nullable return values (as of PHP 7.1) seems to be the next best option.